# Unable to save vectors at 10m using reduceToVectors function in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a simple code for calculating NDWI and extracting water bodies using Sentinel 2 data.

The water bodies need to be vector and at 10 m resolution. To achieve this, I followed the following steps, i.e. converting the waterbody raster to a binary image and then using the `reduceToVectors` function.

I am facing the problem while exporting the vectors to Google drive. Firstly, it takes lots of time, i.e.more than 12 hrs. Secondly, I get `“Error: Computation timed out. (Error code: 3)”` even after these many hours.

Since I am new to GEE and coding, I cannot understand how this function works and where I am making a mistake?

Please note that I can generate vectors at the scale of 15 m but not at 10 m.

```
//*********************************************************************************
// Function to Convert Water raster to vectos
//*********************************************************************************
var water2vectors = function(image){
  var vectors = ee.FeatureCollection(image.toInt().reduceToVectors({
  geometry: States,
  crs: image.projection(),
  scale: 10,
  geometryType: 'Polygon',
  eightConnected: false,
  maxPixels: 1e16,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(),
  tileScale: 16,
  bestEffort: true
}));
  return vectors;
}
//*********************************************************************************

//*********************************************************************************
//Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band.
//*********************************************************************************
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60')
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
  // Return the masked and scaled data, without the QA bands.
  return image.updateMask(mask)//.divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
}
//*********************************************************************************
var States = gaul1.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Maharashtra'))
var collection18_Jan = S2.filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10))
                         .filterDate('2018-01-1' ,'2018-01-31')
                         .filterBounds(geometry)
                         .map(maskS2clouds);

// Mosaic all the images by finding the median values of all the pixels, thus giving a sealess mosaic
var median18_Jan = collection18_Jan.median().clip(geometry);

//calculate NDWI on clipped pixels
var NDWI18_Jan = median18_Jan.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI18_Jan')
var threshold18_Jan = 0.0233;
// Mask the non-watery parts of the image, where NDWI < otsu threshold.
var ndwiMasked18_Jan = NDWI18_Jan.updateMask(NDWI18_Jan.gte(ee.Number(threshold18_Jan)));
//*********************************************************************************
//*********************************************************************************
//Clip all the outputs to the study area. 
//*********************************************************************************
//Create Final NDWI images
var NDWI_2018_Jan = ndwiMasked18_Jan.clip(States) ;
//*********************************************************************************

//********************************************************************************
//Generate Binary Images
//*********************************************************************************
//First step generate binary NDWI images
var NDWI18_Jan_bin = NDWI18_Jan.gte(threshold18_Jan).and(NDWI18_Jan.lt(1)).multiply(1);
//*********************************************************************************
var NDWI18_Jan_vectors = water2vectors(NDWI18_Jan_bin)
Map.addLayer(NDWI18_Jan_vectors)
//*********************************************************************************

var FCC_Jan_2018 = median18_Jan.clip(States);
var ndwiViz = {min: 0.1, max: 1, palette: ['44c9f1', '1637f1']};
var ndwiCompositeViz = {min: 0.1, max: 1, palette: ['#FFB6C1', '#FF1493']};
var ndwiWPF = {min: 15, max: 61, palette: ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Blue']};
//*********************************************************************************

//*********************************************************************************
// Adding Layers
//*********************************************************************************
///2017
// Visualise the mosaic as a false colour image. 
Map.addLayer(FCC_Jan_2018, {bands: ['B8', 'B4', 'B3'], min: 500, max: 3000, gamma: 1.5}, 'Sentinel_2 mosaic17_May');
//Visualise only water pixels from NDWI
Map.addLayer(NDWI_2018_Jan, ndwiViz, 'NDWI18 Masked Jan');

//*********************************************************************************
//Exports
//*********************************************************************************
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: NDWI18_Jan_vectors,
    description: 'NDWI18_Jan_vectors',
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'NDWI18_Jan_vectors',
    fileFormat: 'SHP',
    });
//*********************************************************************************
```

The Link to the code is below:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/3a13abde94195d0d4dea2cbbf744a1ca

Comment: Vector data cannot be defined with spatial resolution. Instead, the CRS defines the properties of vector data. Spatial resolution is usually associated with raster data. Could you please clarify this discrepancy?

Comment: Thank you Aron for clarifying.When I set the scale to 10 meters in above code I am not able to save the vectors in Google Drive. I need vectors at 10m.

Answer (score 0):

The area you are trying to rasterize is simply too big to compute for the scale you set.
You can either try to increase the scale or reduce your area of study (I could export the file with a scale of 1000 m  and setting bestEffort as false).